# Angular testing Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I've got a ModalComponent which accepts some properties from parent via @Input.

That causes the problem with testing

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Name is being used in ngOnInit and should come from `@Input displayeddata`.

How do I pass it in my unit test?

Currently my test looks so

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ModalComponent, FilterComponent],
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, TranslateModule]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.displayeddata = {
        name: 'One component',
        caption: 'Caption',
        componentName: 'TextareaComponent'
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

That is the one test for my component and fails.

### Update #1

Here is what I get on `console.log(this.displayeddata);`

```
Object
caption: "Caption"
component: "TextareaComponent"
name: "One component"
```

I also changed my code a bit (updated code) and now getting a new error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'caption' of undefined`

### Update #2

modal.component.ts

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() showenpunctsnow;
@Input() displayeddata;
@Output() ComponentParametrsInputs: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        caption: ['', Validators.required],
        component: ['']
    });
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {

        console.log(this.displayeddata);

        this.ComponentParametrsInputs = this.fb.group({
            name: [this.displayeddata.name, Validators.required],
            caption: [this.displayeddata.caption, Validators.required],
            component: [this.displayeddata.componentName]
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your component - especially the class definition, variables, constructor and ngOnInit()?

Comment: @dmcgrandle done

Comment: When I console log assigned values in form builder it prints out all the values correctly. I can't understand what's exactly wrong with the code

Comment: For me the issue was resolved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/75510787/11361432

Answer (score 32):

Just gonna comment here even though this has already been solved in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

The issue most likely arrises from the html file rather than the unit test or component itself.

Within your html file:

- Go to where you are using `{variable}.name`
- within the respective section, div, or otherwise add `*ngIf="{variable}"`

This should check to see if this variable exists first.
Then within your unit tests, simply do:

```
it('should create', ()=> {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
}
```

If you want to then check to see if the component will load with a specified `name`:

```
it('should create with specified name', () => {
   component.{variable}.name = 'Foo'

   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.innerHTML)
    .toContain(component.{variable}.name)
}
```

Comment: I was stuck on this problem for 2 days and your answer immediately helped me, thank you very much!

Comment: ```*ngIf="{variable}"``` it´s a beauty!

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 5):

I am putting this update as an "answer" because it won't fit in a comment.  :)

Thank you for posting the component logic.  With this information I had enough to throw together a quick stackblitz testing environment here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53086352?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts

I had to deviate slightly from your code above in the following ways:

- Both FilterComponent and TranslateModule are commented out since I don't have access to that code and you aren't testing them at this point.
- You were using 'async' incorrectly in the second 'beforeEach' function as well as the 'it' spec - you weren't wrapping the arrow function inside an async, you were using the async reserved word to define the function as asynchronous - part of async/await, which is a totally different thing.  You need another set of brackets after the word async to call it as the angular/core/testing function and not the javascript reserved word.  :)
- I added a simple template which displays one of the displaydata variables

However, the surprising thing was when I put your code in stackblitz - it all works just fine!  So clearly the issue you are running into is being caused by some code that is outside of what you have presented so far.

My suggestion for next steps:

- Either edit the existing stackblitz I put together or fork it to your own account to play with it.
- add additional code/data until the problem reoccurs.  This will point to where the actual error is.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem was with html template. I figured it out while being deleting parts and checking if the tests are solved. *ngIf solved that

Comment: It's strange that I've never run into this before. I usually use the *ngIf pattern on all my components just so nothing empty loads, but this is the first time I've had to use it just for a test! Great tip, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If it is about a property in an html template, make sure to check for undefined...

e.g. `<some-component *ngIf="someObject.property === somevalue" ..` make sure to check the object is defined, like this: `<some-component *ngIf="someObject?.property === somevalue" .`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good, I think it's failing because of the async. Try this :

```
it('should create', () => {
    component.displayeddata = {
        name: 'One component',
        caption: 'Caption',
        component: 'TextareaComponent'
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: I added `async` just in case it would work. It's not working either

Comment: Once more, your approach is good. If you want to test an Input (or some variable) in your component, you juste have to do 'component.data = something', and 'fixture.detectChanges()'. It is weird that despite that, the value stay undefined. Can you add more details ? Maybe print 'displayeddata' on le ngOnInit to be sure that's the problem in your test ?

Comment: How do I print it in testing? I've tried console.log but didn't succeed

Comment: console.log in the ngOnInit, the output will be in the navigator console of the launched tests.