# UNIT TEST ANGULAR ---> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm having a problem creating the test file for the post-detail component.
I always get this error:

[image: image of error]

Here is my post-detail.component.ts file:

[image: post-detail.component.ts]

Here is my post-detail.component.spec.ts file:

[image: post-detail.component.spec.ts]

could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read the name property of undefined (in the `PostDetailComponent`, code row 24, `name: this.user.name`), because when you declare your component, the field `user` is not defined. That's why it tries to read the `name` field of the user object.
You have a few ways to fix it:

1. **Add the optional chaining operator** to the reading of the `name` property. You will have the next code on the 24th row: `name: this.user?.name,`.
2. You can **mock the user object in your tests**. In the spec file on the 34th row mock the class field: `component.user = {} as User;`. Then when your component tries to read the name property, you will have an empty object, but not undefined and you will have no errors.